# Google Colab wont connect to local runtime after update

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, localhost, runtime, google-colaboratory

I recently updated jupter_over_ws to version 0.0.7 and now Google Colab refuses to connect my local runtime.

I have tried multiple iterations of launching the localhost in chrome, running with --no-browser etc and keep receiving a 'Forbidden' 403.

The last iteration I got to in an attempt to connect to the notebook was:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 --notebook-dir="" --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True --port=8888
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing the password from the jupyter .config file, then copy and pasting the token url as you have outlined in the answers above, and as outlined in the official colab documentation:

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Answer (score 2):

Colab recently updated it's [local runtime connection instructions](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

In particular, you'll need to provide the URL printed in the console when starting the local runtime.

Clicking the "More Details" button in the local connection dialog will provide additional instructions.

Comment: Many thanks - I actually solved this by removing the password from the jupyter config file, then copy and pasting the token url as you have outlined above.

Comment: if this was not the solution (you password thing is) you should add that as an answer and mark that as a solution, not this one.

Answer (score 2):

After update, you need first upgrade jupyter_http_over_ws:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter_http_over_ws
```

And second, everytime you start the server with this code:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

It will show a new token in Anaconda's prompt, you need to copy.

When you click in `Connect to local runtime` in Colab, a box will ask for the token, then paste there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Anaconda, you can follow the instructions:

1. Open cmd.exe as Administrator
2. Run `pip install --upgrade jupyter_http_over_ws>=0.0.7 &&  jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws`
3. Run `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8892 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0`
4. Copy the URL from the command prompt printed console  ex: `http://localhost:8892/?token=fecaca2501d00f89971ab8fb4a5add3ff682ade7e63f7265`
5. Paste the *URL including token*  in Google Colab connection settings as Backend URL